# Can we check blink property supported in cross-browser using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How to check blink property in CSS supported in cross-browser using JQuery

FireFox: 'text-decoration:blink'  will supports, but other browser will not support.

I want to check in Javascript file whether corresponding browser supports or not using JQuery

Comment: I can't imagine anyone wanting to use a blink tag on purpose, and devising JS substitute when not present. But you've blown my mind and for that I thank you.

Comment: @GregPettit: If it does, I will remove my question

Comment: If the background behind your question is that you want to implement your own blink so that it will work in _all_ browsers, [here's a jsfiddle I did a while back](http://jsfiddle.net/6a36b/) for a [question about formatting for Christmas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8350691/615754) - it's more complicated than a standard blink because of the first bit that was the answer to that question, but the Christmas lights blink part that was my contribution is only about three lines (so I'm sure you can figure out what to do from there).

Answer (score 1):

There is this **[nice article](http://ryanmorr.com/archives/detecting-browser-css-style-support)** which has both function to determine if the style is supported and as well as the assigned value to the style is supported.

I hope it helps.